# Why are references to elements owned by extracted nodes valid but not usable?

Tags: c++

[cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set/extract) says this about `std::set` nodes:

> Pointers and references to the extracted element remain valid, but cannot be used while element is owned by a node handle: they become usable if the element is inserted into a container.

The same rule applies to all STL node-based containers.

Why did the standard make that decision?

It is especially disturbing to have a reference that is "valid but not usable". Does it occur in other circumstances?

Comment: Might be something to do with how they are mutable in a node handle but not in a container

Comment: Yes, I just answered my own question by linking that answer.

Answer (score 0):

The related questions section lead me to [that answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52742172/11350445) to the exact same question.

TL;DR: Introducing mutability and allowing the use of references at the same time would be a violation of the strict aliasing rule.